# LINQ Group By x-number of days

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects 
`List<StatisticsData>`

```
   public class StatisticsData
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

Sample values:

```
22-02-2020 | StatisticsData 
21-02-2020 | StatisticsData 
20-02-2020 | StatisticsData
19-02-2020 | StatisticsData 
19-02-2020 | StatisticsData 
18-02-2020 | StatisticsData
17-02-2020 | StatisticsData 
16-02-2020 | StatisticsData 
15-02-2020 | StatisticsData
```

My goal is to divide it into batches for X days. For example, if I want to take entries for 2 days, in result I will recieve:

First batch:

```
 22-02-2020 | StatisticsData 
 21-02-2020 | StatisticsData
```

Second batch:

```
 20-02-2020 | StatisticsData
 19-02-2020 | StatisticsData 
 19-02-2020 | StatisticsData
```

Third batch:

```
 18-02-2020 | StatisticsData
 17-02-2020 | StatisticsData
```

Etc...

I am stuck to make it with LINQ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Decide on some "epoch" where the two-day slots will start (e.g. `DateTime.MinValue` to avoid ever worrying about negative values), and then group by slot index:

```cs
var batches = data.GroupBy(stat => (int) (stat.EndTime - DateTime.MinValue).TotalDays / 2);
```

Comment: My first question on SoF and got answered by Jon Skeet. Thank you, Jon. It seems exactly that I looked for.

Answer (score 1):

Other possible solution is that by using `Ticks` as follow:

```
long batchPeriod = (TimeSpan.TicksPerDay * 2);
var batches = data.GroupBy(g => g.EndTime.Ticks % batchPeriod);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try group by index:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(40,25);
var groupByRecords = 10;
var groupedList = list
    .Select((x, i) => new { value = x, index = i })
    .GroupBy( x=> x.index / groupByRecords)
    .Select(x => x.Select(y => y.value));
```

Edited: will not work if multiple entries per day, sorry.